# Is it possible to speed up dynamic programming problem using coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have [following implementation](https://github.com/dzmitrykashlach/algorithms-storehouse/blob/main/benchmarks/src/main/kotlin/LongestCommonSubsequenceMemoization.kt) of Longest Common Subsequence problem: recursion + memoization table.
My question is: is it possible to  use coroutines so that code become more performant at the cost of using async functions ?
Could someone suggest an idea(link to guide/article or so), how to implement it ?
[Benchmark is here](https://github.com/dzmitrykashlach/algorithms-storehouse/blob/main/benchmarks/src/main/kotlin/LCSBenchmark.kt).

Thank you in advance ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coroutines are a powerful tool for writing asynchronous code, but they aren't necessarily the best fit for speeding up dynamic programming problems like the Longest Common Subsequence (LCS) problem you've provided. The primary benefit of coroutines is that they enable you to efficiently manage concurrency when dealing with non-blocking IO operations or other tasks that can be run in parallel. However, in the case of the LCS problem, the primary bottleneck is likely the computation itself, not waiting for IO operations.

To speed up your dynamic programming solution, you might consider using parallelism or multithreading to divide the work among multiple CPU cores. In Kotlin, you can use the `kotlinx.coroutines` library to leverage parallelism with its `async` and `await` constructs. Here's an example of how you might modify the `lcs` function to make use of parallelism:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.awaitAll
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope

suspend fun lcs(index1: Int, index2: Int): String = coroutineScope {
    if (index1 == s1.length || index2 == s2.length) {
        return@coroutineScope ""
    }
    if (s1[index1] == s2[index2]) {
        if (memoization[index1][index2] == "") {
            memoization[index1][index2] =
                s1[index1] + lcs(index1 + 1, index2 + 1)
        }
        memoization[index1][index2]
    } else {
        if (memoization[index1][index2] == "") {
            val op1 = async { lcs(index1, index2 + 1) }
            val op2 = async { lcs(index1 + 1, index2) }
            val results = awaitAll(op1, op2)
            memoization[index1][index2] = if (results[0].length > results[1].length) results[0] else results[1]
        }
        memoization[index1][index2]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for advice, will try it out. Additional question about memoization table: do I need it to synchronize it as it can be updated by several coroutines ? I guess not, since array update is atomic, but just wanted to double-check.

Comment: Yes, correct. That individual array element updates are atomic, but you still need to be careful with the memoization table in a concurrent setting. While the array update itself is atomic, you might still encounter race conditions due to the way the table is being read and updated.

Comment: Ex: consider two coroutines that are both executing the `lcs` function and trying to update the same `memoization` entry. Coroutine A reads the value of `memoization[index1][index2]` and finds it to be an empty string, while Coroutine B reads the same value before Coroutine A has had a chance to update it. Both coroutines then proceed to update the value, which can lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: One way to avoid this issue is to use a synchronization mechanism, such as a `Mutex` from the `kotlinx.coroutines.sync` package. You can lock the critical section of your code to ensure that only one coroutine can access the memoization table at a time.